# jquery - Submit form using 2 buttons with one of them opening in new tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, form-submit

I've a form which is used to submit a post. I want to place a button to save the post and another to preview the post in new tab. Here is the code as of now but it doesn't work.

```
    <form id="postForm" method="POST">
      .....
      <button id=save>Save</button>
      <button id="preview">Preview</button>
    </form>

    $('#preview').click(function(){
                var form=$('#postForm');
                form.serialize();
                form.target="_blank";
                form.action="preview.php";
                form.submit();
            });
    $('#save').click(function(){
                var form=$('#postForm');
                form.serialize();
                form.action="save.php";
                form.submit();
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change it to the following:

```
$('#preview').click(function(){
            var form=$('#postForm');
            form.attr('target',"_blank");
            form.attr('action',"preview.php");
        });
$('#save').click(function(){
            var form=$('#postForm');
            form.attr('action',"save.php");
        });
```

You don't need to call `form.submit()`. Also, the form will serialize itself.